# Loading images from CSS stylesheet that is on remote host

Tags: css, image, loading

I have the following files structure:

```
On server 'site1.com':
- images\background.jpg
- index.html

On server 'site2.com':
- css\main.css
```

On the file 'index.html', on site1.com, i am point to the stylesheet on site2.com/css/main.css.

On the file 'main.css' i have a rule that says: `background-image: url(images/background.jpg);`

The problem is that the file 'index.html' is not loading 'background.jpg' as its background. How can I fix that? The only way is writing the absolute path `background-image: url(site1.com/images/background.jpg);` at the stylesheet rule?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try inline css , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28872505/2218697) to show div with background image in Email newsletter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use full link `background-image: url(http://site1.com/images/background.jpg);`
and absolute path doesn't include domain.
Example for absolute path `background-image:url(/images/background.jpg);`

Comment: Thanks warlord! Is that a way of not doing that? A have a dozen of CSS files, I would have to to that in every one of them.

Comment: @user1504820 If I understand you correctly, you don't want to set this link in every css files?

Comment: In fact, I see no other solution and already put the absolute path in every background on the CSS file, but I still wanted to know if there is a way more direct of doing that than to change each URL everytime I change the server.

Comment: @user1504820 In my opinion that's the best solution for your problem. You can try to write PHP script, which will automatically set your current domain, but I think it's not good option. Also I'd recommend you to minimize number of requests to css files, so pages will load faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since URLs referenced inside of a CSS file are relative to the CSS file itself it would not load background.jpg from site1.com. So you can either use the full URL for the image file in your CSS or alternatively you can load an additional style sheet with your site specific styles.

You would load the CSS from site2.com first, then load the CSS from site1.com after. In this case the only style in your site1 CSS file would be `background-image: url(images/background.jpg);` Since this new CSS file is hosted on site1.com it will reference the images folder correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup:

```
On server 'site1.com':
    - images\background.jpg
    - index.html

On server 'site2.com':
    - css\main.css
```

File 'index.html' will not load 'background.jpg' as its background, because `main.css` & `background.jpg` are on different domains.

**REASON:**
When you write a relative path  `images/background.jpg`, server assumes that all these relative paths are **relative** to `main.css`, not relative to any `*.html` or `*.php` file using `main.css`. 
So `images/background.jpg` is assumed as `site2.com/images/background.jpg`, which does not exist and thus image does not load.

**SOLUTION:**
To use `background.jpg` in `index.html` by writing a relative path `background-image: url(images/background.jpg);`, try moving `images` folder to `site2.com` Then you can write the `relative path` for any resource you want to use in `main.css`.

Your setup in this case should be:

```
On server 'site1.com':
    - index.html

On server 'site2.com':
    - css\main.css
    - images\background.jpg
```

and your CSS Rule should be:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
```

Which translates to: Go up one directory from current directory(`css`) and then go in `images` and get `background.jpg` to use it as background image.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to use the full URLs, however, nothing prevents you in handling your image URLs at client-side or server-side functions.