# HTML Email Background Image

Tags: html, css, email

I'm coding a HTML email and so far it's working pretty well. I opted to use a background image for ease of consistency and the solution I'm using is from the following thread:

[html email with background-image style not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689862/html-email-with-background-image-style-not-shown)

It's working well in the mail clients I test (Outlook, Hotmail, GMail and Mail) however in some clients, the background image of the cell is repeating itself across the browser window (as though the image is applied to the body tag). If I set the body tag to 600px instead of 100% it fixes the issue, I'll only see the background once in all clients but when I do that, in Outlook, the text content vanishes.

Can anyone suggest a solution to fix this for me?

My whole code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>Metanium</title>

<style type="text/css">

    #outlook a{
        padding:0;
    }
    body{
        width:100% !important;
    }
    .ReadMsgBody{
        width:100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass{
        width:100%;
    }
    body{
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    }
    body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    img{
        border:0;
        height:auto;
        line-height:100%;
        outline:none;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    table td{
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    #backgroundTable{
        height:100% !important;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100% !important;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section background color
@tip Set the background color for your email. You may want to choose one that matches your company's branding.
@theme page
*/
    body,#backgroundTable{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FAFAFA;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section email border
@tip Set the border for your email.
*/
    #templateContainer{
        /*@editable*/border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section heading 1
@tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails. These should be the largest of your headings.
@style heading 1
*/
    h1,.h1{
        /*@editable*/color:#202020;
        display:block;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:34px;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right:0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-left:0;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section heading 2
@tip Set the styling for all second-level headings in your emails.
@style heading 2
*/
    h2,.h2{
        /*@editable*/color:#202020;
        display:block;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:30px;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right:0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-left:0;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section heading 3
@tip Set the styling for all third-level headings in your emails.
@style heading 3
*/
    h3,.h3{
        /*@editable*/color:#202020;
        display:block;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:26px;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right:0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-left:0;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Page
@section heading 4
@tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
@style heading 4
*/
    h4,.h4{
        /*@editable*/color:#202020;
        display:block;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:22px;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        margin-top:0;
        margin-right:0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        margin-left:0;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section preheader style
@tip Set the background color for your email's preheader area.
@theme page
*/
    #templatePreheader{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FAFAFA;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section preheader text
@tip Set the styling for your email's preheader text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
*/
    .preheaderContent div{
        /*@editable*/color:#505050;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:10px;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section preheader link
@tip Set the styling for your email's preheader links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
*/
    .preheaderContent div a:link,.preheaderContent div a:visited,.preheaderContent div a .yshortcuts {
        /*@editable*/color:#336699;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section header style
@tip Set the background color and border for your email's header area.
@theme header
*/
    #templateHeader{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
        /*@editable*/border-bottom:0;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section header text
@tip Set the styling for your email's header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
*/
    .headerContent{
        /*@editable*/color:#202020;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:34px;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:bold;
        /*@editable*/line-height:100%;
        /*@editable*/padding:0;
        /*@editable*/text-align:center;
        /*@editable*/vertical-align:middle;
    }
/*
@tab Header
@section header link
@tip Set the styling for your email's header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
*/
    .headerContent a:link,.headerContent a:visited,.headerContent a .yshortcuts {
        /*@editable*/color:#336699;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
    }
    #headerImage{
        height:auto;
        max-width:600px !important;
    }
/*
@tab Body
@section body style
@tip Set the background color for your email's body area.

    #templateContainer,.bodyContent{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
*/
/*
@tab Body
@section body text
@tip Set the styling for your email's main content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
@theme main
*/
    .bodyContent div{
        /*@editable*/color:#505050;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:14px;
        /*@editable*/line-height:150%;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Body
@section body link
@tip Set the styling for your email's main content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
*/
    .bodyContent div a:link,.bodyContent div a:visited,.bodyContent div a .yshortcuts {
        /*@editable*/color:#336699;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .bodyContent img{
        display:inline;
        height:auto;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section footer style
@tip Set the background color and top border for your email's footer area.
@theme footer
*/
    #templateFooter{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
        /*@editable*/border-top:0;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section footer text
@tip Set the styling for your email's footer text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
@theme footer
*/
    .footerContent div{
        /*@editable*/color:#707070;
        /*@editable*/font-family:Arial;
        /*@editable*/font-size:12px;
        /*@editable*/line-height:125%;
        /*@editable*/text-align:left;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section footer link
@tip Set the styling for your email's footer links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
*/
    .footerContent div a:link,.footerContent div a:visited,.footerContent div a .yshortcuts {
        /*@editable*/color:#336699;
        /*@editable*/font-weight:normal;
        /*@editable*/text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .footerContent img{
        display:inline;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section social bar style
@tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer social bar.
@theme footer
*/
    #social{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FAFAFA;
        /*@editable*/border:0;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section social bar style
@tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer social bar.
*/
    #social div{
        /*@editable*/text-align:center;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section utility bar style
@tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer utility bar.
@theme footer
*/
    #utility{
        /*@editable*/background-color:#FFFFFF;
        /*@editable*/border:0;
    }
/*
@tab Footer
@section utility bar style
@tip Set the background color and border for your email's footer utility bar.
*/
    #utility div{
        /*@editable*/text-align:center;
    }
    #monkeyRewards img{
        max-width:190px;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable">

<tr>
<td background="http://clients.networkdm.co.uk/externalresources/emailparts/5435/bg.jpg" height="895" width="600">
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block;position:absolute; height:895px; width:600px;top:0;left:0;border:0;z-index:1;' src="http://clients.networkdm.co.uk/externalresources/emailparts/5435/bg.jpg"/>
<v:shape xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theText" style='behavior: url(#default#VML); display:inline-block;position:absolute; height:895px; width:600px;top:-5;left:-10;border:0;z-index:2;'>
<div>
<![endif]-->
<!-- This is where you nest a table with the content that will float over the image -->

<table height="895" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

    <tr>
        <td height="263" width="600" valign="top" style="padding:0px; padding-top: 215px; padding-left: 338px; padding-right: 20px; width: 242px;">
            <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; color: #5a488f; width: 600px;">
                We are giving away an exclusive set of seven Metanium Everyday baby 
                grows every day for the rest of 2012 - one for every day of the week!
                <br /><br />
            </span>

            <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; color: #5a488f; width: 600px;">
                Each daily winner will also receive a full size sample of Metanium 
                Everyday Barrier Ointment.
                <br /><br />
                To enter*, and for terms and conditions, visit our online competition 
                page by clicking on the link below.
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="45" width="600" valign="top" align="center">
            <img src="http://clients.networkdm.co.uk/externalresources/emailparts/5435/enter.jpg" alt="Click here to enter!" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="600" valign="top" align="left" style="padding: 0px; padding-left: 163px; padding-top: 25px; padding-right: 140px; width: 297px;">
            <img src="http://clients.networkdm.co.uk/externalresources/emailparts/5435/protection.jpg" alt="Everyday nappy rash protection" /><br /><br />

            <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.4; color: #5a488f; width: 600px;">
                New Metanium Everyday Barrier Ointment has a unique double action
                formula to provide protection from nappy rash. It doesn't contain
                fragrance or lanolin, so is gentle enough to use at each nappy change.
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would try adding "height:100%" in the body css also. Not exactly sure why, but from my experience it solved some issues.

Answer (score 4):

Your wrapper table is set to be 100% wide, while the cell with the background has a pixel width. That's not how tables are supposed to work.

Make the table and cell width the same for the background image.

Center the table with css, or by wrapping it with another table. Whatever works.

Comment: I've seen things...terrible things...and I've had to make them work in Lotus Notes.

Comment: This is still causing my text content to vanish in Outlook. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reading your code, it appears the spans are wider than their container should allow. Try removing the 600px width from your spans. They should only have room to be ~300px wide.

Comment: Still getting the same result. I tried removing the background image which does succeed in getting the text to show up so I'm assuming that for some reason the background image table is above the content. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Hmm...clutching at straws, what about using an inline, style="background: url(http://clients.networkdm.co.uk/externalresources/emailparts/5435/bg.jpg) no-repeat;" instead of the background attribute? Worth a shot, might lose you compatibility elsewhere though...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19100/discussion-between-0neji-and-puppybeard)