# Background-image css inside an html email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to send mail with the image embedded as mail body. Below is the code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <div style="background: url(http://localhost/image/mvp-bg.jpg) no-repeat top left; width: 800px; height:685px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px;">
    <div style="width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 80px;">
        <p>Mail Body</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Could some one let me know how to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: If your sending email, you wont be able to reference localhost on the clients machine unless they have a web server set up with the same directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

For email templates better refer the images from server instead of `localhost`, You cannot expect the user will have the images loaded in their localhost :)

Change it to `url(http://domain.com/image/mvp-bg.jpg)`

Comment: changing the url similat to "http://domain.com/image/mvp-bg.jpg" did not fix my issue. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from [html email with background-image style not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689862/html-email-with-background-image-style-not-shown) . Also below is the code i modified so that css are rendered properly in mail. When using  tags the css were not rendering, so instaed used table tags.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
   <head>
   <style type="text/css">
    v\:*
    {
        behavior: url(#default#VML);
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table style="background-image: url('image/mvp-bg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;width: 800px; height:685px; margin: 0 auto; color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px;" >
    <!--[if gte vml 1]>
                <v:shape 
                    stroked='f'
                     style='position:absolute;margin-left:-90pt;margin-top:-1.55pt;     
                            z-index:-503306481;
                            visibility:visible;
                            width:720pt;
                            height:475pt;           
                            top:0;
                            left:0;
                            border:0;                                               
                            '>
                    <v:imagedata src="http://www.domain.com/image/mvp-bg.jpg"/>
                </v:shape>
        <![endif]-->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <div style="width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 85px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px;">                        
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding: 10px; color: #ffffff;">
                               Mail Body
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>                        
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```