# How to code propper HTML mails for MS Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, phpmailer

I am developing an php app which sends finally styled html mails with PHPMailer, inlcuding logos etc.. A number of mail apps receive and displays this mails perfect, but not Outlook on PC. It simply ignores all : HTML code and simple text. Weired.

Does anyone can give some hints what to do , where to look to satisfy MS Outlook ?

This question is NOT about common HTML programming issues but about WHAT does OUTLOOK need to get satisfied to show html mails. I red that OUTLOOK uses Word to render mails. So which kind of HTML does Word expect ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What guidelines for HTML email design are there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there)

Comment: @ Alex K. No - that link gives common tips on html programming, nice to read but does not reflect my specific question on Outlook. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If Outlook is not displaying HTML then the HTML is formed in such a way that Outlook is not capable displaying it, that question gives advice on what it will be able to handle.  Send a very simple HTML test message and you would expect to see it rendered correctly.

Comment: it gives hints, yes - but does not reflect the problem from above - in this case Outlook (PC)  simply shows `nothing` , neither html nor simple text. But other mail apps does, i.e Lotus Notes and Apple Mail. Haven't tested it further yet.