# HTML email development with different testing outcomes

Tags: html, css

Im testing an e-mail I made from scratch. I’m using litmus and mail chimp and they are both giving me different outcomes.

Anyone know why this happens and which one do I go with?

Comment: is it for a specific email client like outlook, gmail etc?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not copied any code, I'm assuming you followed the HTML email development guidelines as you cannot code it like it is a webpage?

[What guidelines for HTML email design are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there)

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the issues I've came across in MailChimp outlook rendering which you may not see in other email testing tools.

https://mailchimp.com/help/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook/

Without knowing the exact issue I can not assure about this, but to confirm whether issue is in MailChimp and not Litmus, you can test your HTML in other testing tools like EmailOnAcid. EmailOnAcid is another nice tool I've used.